# Math notation for summing up the rows in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Lets say I have a 100 row by 200 column matrix $\phi$, is there any standard notation or something which defines the vector $\Phi$ which has the same amount of columns (i.e. 200 columns), but all the rows summed up into just one row?

Something like we use $\sum$ for elements of a set or iterating over a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, $\Phi=(1,1,\ldots,1)\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering whether there was some notation for this, because it seems like something people use often.

Comment: @jbx I don't think there is a notation for this, at least not a popular one, but in some occasions, people will write "$\Phi=e^\top\phi$", "$\Phi=\mathbf{1}^\top\phi$" or "$\Phi=u^\top\phi$", and states that $e$ or $\mathbf{1}$ or $u$ means "a vector of ones". In other occasions, people may simply refer to $\Phi$ as "the sum of all rows of $\phi$".

Comment: Thanks, $1^T\phi$ and separately specifying that $1$ is a vector of (1,1, ..., 1) seems acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rencher & Schaalje book on linear models](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471754986) uses the notation $\mathbf{j} = (1,1, ..., 1)$, where $\mathbf{j}$ is a column vector of $1$s.  Then $ \mathbf{j'A} $ is the column sums of $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{Aj}$ is the row sums of $\mathbf{A}$.

If you want the column sums of $\phi$, we have $\mathbf{\Phi} = \mathbf{j}'\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that this is the 'standard' way then...